# Redirect Assets Using AWS S3 / CloudFront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have a file that I want to rename, and I want to redirect incoming requests to the new file name.

Can I do this with AWS settings?  I'm hoping I can setup a permanent alias in S3, so that the correct file gets copied out to CloudFront.

I found this doc on aliasing, but I'm not sure if it's what I need.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resource-record-sets-choosing-alias-non-alias.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure this out after further digging in the S3 interface and using this post:

[Amazon S3 Redirect and Cloudfront](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22740084/amazon-s3-redirect-and-cloudfront)

Redirects can be setup using metadata with a key "Website Redirect Location" and the new URL as the value.