# AWS Cloudfront redirected you too many times

Tags: amazon-cloudfront, cloudflare, amazon-route53

I have a problem with redirects in cloudfront.

---

- I configure Cloudflare two NS in my webpanel first.

I follow this steps after this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42869783/3332734

[image]

- In `cloudfront` I pointed my two buckets.
- In my two buckets, I set `hosting website` and redirect with `bestdestiny.panel.adm.br` with `https` prefix

See my buckets config below:

[image]

[image]

and each bucket has the respective policy rule:

[image]

And this is my cloudfront config below:

[image]

[image]

but...

[image]

Comment: The reason for the problem seems obvious enough -- you have configured CloudFront to send requests to a bucket and you have configured the bucket to redirect requests to the same CloudFront distribution that is sending the requests to the bucket.  It's a redirect loop.   What you do not seem to have mentioned is why you created two buckets or why they are in two different regions, but the question you cited is for creating two sites, one with `www` and one without.  You're not doing that here, so it doesn't seem like you should be configuring that redirect in S3.

Comment: Solved! 
I followed these recommendations to fix it with custom error pages:
https://serverfault.com/a/815741/102749

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the root of your issue is a redirect loop. You've set up CloudFront to direct requests to an S3 bucket, and simultaneously, you've instructed the S3 bucket to redirect requests back to the very same CloudFront distribution. This creates a continuous loop of redirects.

While you mentioned two buckets in different regions, it's unclear why they were set up this way, especially since the reference you provided is about creating two separate sites (one with `www` and another without).

If your intention is not to create two sites, it might be best to reconsider the redirect configuration in your S3 bucket.

Comment: Thanks for providing a great explanation. Indeed redirect requests option in the S3 bucket was a bad choice in my setup. Since that time I've learned much more about AWS bucket configuration.