# Redirect mydomain.com to www.mydomain.com - Amazon

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I'm trying to redirect site's root to www (www.mysite.com) instead of pure domain (mysite.com) at aws, but I do not get how to do this. I configured the CNAME in the route 53, the functions on lambda and cloudfront as well. Anyway anyone choise did not solve my problem.

I bought a certificate with *.mysite.com and did not add mysite.com, there is a way to re-buy or change the certificate to add this domain name.

How can I do it?

Comment: This part here: "I configured the CNAME in the route 53, the functions on lambda and cloudfront as well" is really vague. You need to provide the actual details about **HOW** you configured things. What are you even using Lambda for? If all your site traffic is going through CloudFront then you should be using AWS ACM SSL certificates, which are free, instead of having to buy anything. I suggest looking at the answers here regarding CloudFront and redirects: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28675620/cloudfront-redirect-www-to-naked-domain-with-ssl

Comment: I configured all this services with the simplest way possible, I will check this aswer right now.