# How do I point a root domain to a CloudFront distribution serving up S3 static site? I'm on Google Domains

Tags: amazon-web-services, redirect, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I've been reading this [Cloudfront redirect www to naked domain with ssl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28675620/cloudfront-redirect-www-to-naked-domain-with-ssl) as well as other guides.

I need to point all variations of `http` and `www` into `https://example.com`.

I've setup both `example.com` and `www.example.com` S3 buckets and CloudFront distributions with the redirect, but I think I am stumped on how to redirect the root domain to my CloudFront distribution. I'm on Google Domains.

My root CloudFront:

[image]
[image]

My `www` CloudFront:

[image]
[image]

My root S3 bucket:

[image]

My `www` S3 bucket:

[image]

Comment: using 2 cloudfront distributions for `www` and `non-www` separately is unnecessary.

Answer (score -1):

AWS Route53 supports root domain routing to a CloudFront distribution as documented [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/custom-ssl-domain-names-root-domain-hosting-for-amazon-cloudfront/).

In summary, you:

- add an `A type` DNS record to your Route53 HostedZone
- select the `alias` checkbox next to the `value` input
- select your CloudFront distribution from the dropdown `value` input field