# AWS S3 website+cloudfront root domain redirect issues

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, dns, amazon-cloudfront

I have `my-domain.com`.  I want requests to the www subdomain to redirect to the root, and all requests to redirect to https.

I have 2 S3 buckets - `my-domain.com` and `www.my-domain.com` (empty bucket configured to redirect to `my-domain.com`)

I've set up a Cloudfront distro in front of `my-domain.com` for https.

For DNS, I have an A record for `my-domain.com` which is an 'alias' record pointing to the cloudfront distro.  I have another A record for `www.my-domain.com` which is an 'alias' record pointing to the empty `www.my-domain.com` S3 redirection bucket

This results in the following redirects:

http://my-domain.com -> https://my-domain.com

http://www.my-domain.com -> https://my-domain.com

However a request to `https://www.my-domain.com` does not redirect.  I'm presuming this is because there is no https listener for the S3 redirection bucket.  So my question is, is there a better way to do this? I really don't want to have to set up another cloudfront distro just to have this functionality but it feels to me broken if https://www does not redirect correctly.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

@rix,

Perhaps this might be what you are looking for. [AWS S3 website+cloudfront root domain redirect issues]
([Cloudfront redirect www to naked domain with ssl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28675620/cloudfront-redirect-www-to-naked-domain-with-ssl?noredirect=1&lq=1))

Comment: I know that's exactly the same question, it's just a bit older and things tend to change very quickly with AWS and this whole 2xS3 buckets + 2xcloudfront distros is getting a little bit silly in my opinion.  I think I may just alias the www as im not fussed about SEO for this site and this architecture seems simply wrong. It's a pity as S3 hosting is fantastic..