# Amazon Cloudfront appends index.html on redirection from www to naked domain

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have set up two S3 Buckets for `domain.com` and `www.domain.com` and distributions for both on Cloudfront. Bucket with `www` just redirects requests to `non-www` bucket static Endpoint. So basically it repeats steps from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42869783/5233074). The only difference is, I used REST origins instead of static URL provided by S3 Buckets.

The problem is when I'm accessing `www.domain.com` it redirects to `domain.com` but it appends `index.html` at the end of the URL, and this messing with `ReactJS` somehow - the page simply does not render. Direct call to `domain.com` works fine, no `index.html` at the end.

What could be wrong with the setup?

Comment: Is this to do with the [Default Root Object](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/DefaultRootObject.html) configured in CloudFront?

Comment: @madebydavid The distribution for `non-www` bucket uses `Default Root Object`, without it I get access denied. But `www` one, I tried with and without, then thought this might have something to do with cache, so I invalidated it, the result is the same.