# AWS CloudFront and S3, Handling WWW and HTTPS with a Single Redirect

Tags: amazon-web-services, redirect, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I'm trying to setup the redirects such that all variations:
http://example.com, http://www.example.com, https://example.com
redirect to https://www.example.com

I've gone through several other [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28675620/cloudfront-redirect-www-to-naked-domain-with-ssl) and have it working except I'm noticing some weirdness in the redirects.

http://www.example.com -> 301 -> https://www.example.com **Working as Intended**

http://example.com -> 301 -> http://www.example.com -> 301 -> https://www.example.com
**Scenario 1: Is there a way to skip the first 301?**

https://example.com -> 301 -> http://www.example.com -> 301 -> https://www.example.com
**Scenario 2: It actually redirects back to http first. Is there a way to skip the first 301?**

**Setup**
*S3*
Two buckets:

- www.example.com which hosts the site
- example.com, which redirects to www.example.com with https protocol.

*CloudFront*
Two distributions:

- *Distribution one*

  - **custom origin**: www.example.com.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com
  - **alternate cname**: www.example.com
  - **viewer protocol policy**: Redirect HTTP to HTTPS
- *Distribution two*

  - **custom origin**: example.com.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com
  - **alternate cname**: example.com
  - **viewer protocol policy**: HTTP and HTTPS

*Route 53*
A and AAAA records for example.com and www.example.com each pointing to their respective Cloudfront distributions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**for Distribution two**

custom origin: example.com.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com
alternate cname: example.com
viewer protocol policy: **Redirect HTTP to HTTPS**

This way you can avoid this secanrio 2:

> https://example.com -> 301 -> http://www.example.com -> 301 -> https://www.example.com

it will be like this

> https://example.com -> https://www.example.com

Scenario 1 can avoid two times redirection but you can do like this

> http://example.com -> 301 -> https://example.com -> 301 -> https://www.example.com

There is some limitation where you can't ignore 301 redirection while using `cloudfront`.

Comment: Changing that just creates a 3rd redirect  for scenario 1


`http://example.com` -> `https://example.com` -> `http://www.example.com` -> `https://www.example.com`

Comment: it will be two redirection for scenario 1 and for 2 it will reduce to 1.  Because when type https://example.com to https://www.example.com. Check this https://knabfinance.com in here http://redirectcheck.com/index.php

Comment: Yes that site you linked is how I want it to behave, but doing what you suggested doesn't work. Changing distribution 2 to Redirect HTTP to HTTPS does not affect scenario 2 and causes scenario 1 to create 3 redirects. Logically speaking it doesn't make sense for that to work since I'm trying to redirect from `https://example.com` to `https://www.example.com`, which is https to https, so I don't see why using HTTP to HTTPS would work at all.

Comment: Edit: I tried using the site you linked for checking redirects on my site and it matches the behavior that you described. However, using the network console in the browser shows the additional redirects happening.

Comment: give your domain to check what happening. In network console i am getting same behaviour.

Comment: Hm I just tried again and now the network console is showing the same behavior. Very confused, maybe Cloudfront hadn't fully updated yet? But seems like everything is working fine now. Thanks for the help!

Comment: cloudfront changes it took almost 30-60 minutes sometimes. Because they need to update to networking system. Cache behaviour sometime take time to reflect.