# 301 redirect loop when setting up static website with S3, Cloudfront, SSL

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I'm attempting to host a static website in AWS for `example.com` and `www.example.com` using HTTPS. My current setup properly redirects to to `example.com` but hits Chrome with a zillion 301 redirects.

The most promising info was this tutorial:
[Cloudfront redirect www to naked domain with ssl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28675620/cloudfront-redirect-www-to-naked-domain-with-ssl)

and this stackoverflow answer:
[Cloudfront redirect www to naked domain with ssl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28675620/cloudfront-redirect-www-to-naked-domain-with-ssl)

I have two S3 buckets. In the AWS console for S3, `www.example.com` is set to redirect to `example.com` via https, and `example.com` is set to host a static website.

I have two Cloudfront distributions, each using an SSL certificate generated using ACM from the us-east-1 region. Origin Domain Name was set by copy / pasting the corresponding S3 endpoint URL rather than using dropdown autopopulate. Alternate Domain Name is set to the matching domain `www.example.com` or `example.com` for each distribution.

In Route53, I have two A records, one for each domain. Both are able to see their corresponding Cloudfront distributions populate the dropdown in the Alias menu, and have been selected.

The 301 errors seem to come from cloudfront even in the case where I access the S3 endpoints directly using the long form urls (http response in Chrome devtools has a value of `X-Cache: Redirect from cloudfront`).

The website is nothing more than an index.html with some text. No javascript in play.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Burning days on this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I have seen this be solved before is the following:

- Have a CloudFront Distribution for the apex (`example.com`)
- Have a CloudFront Distribution for the `www` subdomain
- Remove any 301 redirecting done in application or from any distribution
- Add a Lambda@Edge function to perform a `302` [redirect](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-examples.html#lambda-examples-http-redirect) on the CloudFront distribution for the `www` domain **only**.

The redirect function would look like this

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
 
     # Generate HTTP redirect response with 302 status code and Location header.
     uri = request = event['Records'][0]['cf']['request']['uri']
    
     response = {
         'status': '302',
         'statusDescription': 'Found',
         'headers': {
             'location': [{
                 'key': 'Location',
                 'value': 'https://example.com/' + uri
             }]
         }
     }
     
     return response
```

The likely reason you're seeing this is that example.com is also redirecting to itself.

Also test with a `302` not a `301`. `301` is a permanent redirect and can cause problems when attempting to rollback any changes for browsers who have already visited this URL.

Comment: thank you for the response.. but, i mean, i'm just trying to set up a simple text website on an S3 bucket with SSL! there is no programming logic whatsoever (not even javascript). do i really need a lambda for this? seems a bit much? maybe i'm missing something.

Comment: Hmm, perhaps Ive misunderstood the question. It seemed like you were doing a redirect but it got caught in a loop and that you wanted it to redirect once. Can you confirm?

Comment: thank you again. yes this is true, i think. however, this seems to be a common config with many tutorials, and none of them mention having to use a lambda. perhaps your solution will work, but, the redirect is simply from www.example.com to example.com. S3 allows redirecting from one bucket to another as part of the static hosting menu. i have not introduced any code that initiates a redirect. 

it just seems a lot to have to rent lambda $ for such a simple thing?

Comment: Yes S3 can do redirects too but can be a little fiddly, Lambda@Edge is just a preferential route for a lot of developers mainly because it works for all origins and removes this logic from the origin :)

Comment: Thats no problem, glad I could help :)

Answer (score -1):

If you are looking for a better way to host your website with S3 and Cloudfront without the pain of using Lambda function, I have created a step by step tutorial for that very purpose, please have a look at
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=94DyGswSY6k&t=1475s