# Wowza+AWS Cloudfront stream availability delay

Tags: cdn, rtsp, amazon-cloudfront, wowza

I'm pretty new to Wowza and Cloudfront.

I'm using Wowza Streaming Engine 4.4.1 together with AWS cloudfront to deliver a live rtsp video stream. I'm able to deliver the video through the CDN, but I noticed a relevant delay (~200 seconds delay on CDN) between the availability of the stream (just after its creation) on the CDN and on the Wowza MCU. Long story short, the stream is not immediately available.

I don't understand the reason of such difference. I need to use the CDN to make the stream easily available to many people, but this delay is making this approach not suitable for my purposes.

Is there some configurations I have to take into account, or is a known "drowback" of using a cloudfront CDN?

Comment: It sounds like you haven't disabled the default [five minute error caching TTL](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35541525/1695906) by setting it to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer is the one pointed out by "Michael - sqlbot".

I updated the value of Error `Caching Minimum TTL` to 0 and now, in case of 404 error, the error is not cached, so subsequent request doesn't get 404 error and the stream become immediately available (~10 seconds delay, but it is just fine).

AWS reference [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/custom-error-pages.html#custom-error-pages-procedure)

Simone