# Deploying CloudFront in front of NodeJS Express

Tags: node.js, express, caching, amazon-cloudfront

I have an app which serves a dynamic html and some static files written in NodeJS/Express.

I deployed an AWS CloudFront distro in front of it, however only the HTML goes through, all the static files result in 404. The headers of the requests look like:

`Age:116
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:170
Content-Security-Policy:default-src 'self'
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Mon, 09 Oct 2017 14:37:23 GMT
Server:nginx/1.6.2
Via:1.1 523db8f46d98334ac6b5debbf315e15b.cloudfront.net (CloudFront), 1.1 proxy1.xxx.yy (squid/4.0.17)
X-Amz-Cf-Id:5UYpluGn8TxUxsxmmDYYiZnjbOWbZ7iFFit55mmgcN6IbAJHCEAX6Q==
X-Cache:MISS from proxy1.xxx.yy
X-Cache:Error from cloudfront
X-Cache-Lookup:MISS from proxy1.xxx.yy:3128
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-Powered-By:Express`

For info, my nodejs app runs in some port, and nginx reverse-proxies it to the domain I specified using `proxy_pass`.

As you can see I'm behind another proxy, but this cannot be the problem.

*What I believe is happening is that my origin looks like `mydomain.com/path/app_id` and express serves static files from `mydomain.com/`.*

Has anyone successfully deployed CloudFront in front of NodeJS/Express for static files? I really don't understand what the problem is..

Thanks!

Comment: I tried adding both origins `mydomain/path/app_id` and `mydomain` but it does not make any difference

Comment: Review your server's logs to see what's actually being requested.  Also, set your [Error Caching Minimum TTL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35541525/1695906) to 0 while testing.  Otherwise CloudFront cached error responses for 5 minutes by default.  As above, `Age: 116` is almost 2 minutes old, and if you solved the problem between now and then, you wouldn't see it and there would be no origin server log entry.

Answer (score 0):

To serve files from another path the flow is as follows:

- Add all necessary origins (in this case `mydomain.com/path/app_id` AND `mydomain.com` (without trailing `/`))
- Add behaviours on your ditribution for every file type. In this case static files are stored in different folders (like `/img`). So we can add behaviours for `img/*`, `js/*` and `css/*`. Then each behaviour can be set to a single origin. In this case we choose `mydomain.com` which was previously named `Static files origin`.