# S3 web page redirect: can't set x-amz-website-redirect-location property

Tags: amazon-web-services, redirect, amazon-s3

I want to use redirects with S3 webpages. The AWS [Configuring a Web Page Redirect](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/how-to-page-redirect.html) document says to set the `x-amz-website-redirect-location` property, but this doesn't seem to be settable. If I try to set the key, S3 prefixes the key with `x-amz-meta-` (making it a [user-defined metadata](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html#object-metadata)) and the modified key doesn't cause a redirect.

I set the metadata with the aws CLI:

```
 aws s3api copy-object --copy-source static.righto.com/zero \
--bucket static.righto.com --key bar \
--metadata x-amz-website-redirect-location=http://righto.com/bar \
--metadata-directive REPLACE
```

but when I look in the S3 console, the metadata name has been prefixed and the redirect is ignored.

The same thing happens if I use the Python API:

```
s3.Bucket('static.righto.com').put_object(Key=src, Body='',
  Metadata={'x-amz-website-redirect-location': dst})
```

And if I try to set the `x-amz-website-redirect-location` metadata key in the S3 console, I get the error "User-defined metadata keys must start with x-amz-meta-."

Did `x-amz-website-redirect-location` become unsupported?

If I set "Website Redirect Location" metadata in the console then redirects work, so issue isn't the redirect endpoint problems in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22740084/amazon-s3-redirect-and-cloudfront). But I can't use "Website Redirect Location" as a metadata key in the API.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `--website-redirect-location <value>`.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/copy-object.html

`x-amz-website-redirect-location` is not *user* metadata (`x-amz-meta-*`), which is what the `--metadata` option is used for.

Comment: I'm confused whether I just need to set that (and on what command, copy?  I'm not copying my website build folder for example, it's already been created) or if I need routing _rules_)

Comment: @PositiveGuy OP was using an empty (0 byte) object he created in the bucket and named `zero`, making a copy of it with the added metadata to the location where he wanted a redirect.   There is some overlap between this functionality and routing rules.  It depends on what you are trying to accomplish, in how many places, and whether there are patterns involved.

Comment: for boto, you can check this link: `https://www.designingforthefuture.com/boto3`
Basically, you've to do `S3.put_object(Bucket=<bkt-name>, 
                    Key=<k-name>, 
                    Body='',
                    WebsiteRedirectLocation='http://example.com')`

Comment: For those trying to solve this using the Java SDK: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61920902/2162886

Comment: For anyone using `aws s3 cp`, then use the flag `--website-redirect` instead