# How do I redirect from an Amazon S3 file to my website?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

[image]

I have a downloadable something.pkg file hosted in an Amazon S3 bucket (https://myassets.s3.amazonaws.com/something.pkg)

many people have this link but I don't want people anymore to be able to download it anymore but to be redirected to my_website.com/file_landing_page/

trying to edit the metadata of the file (as seen in the photo), setting the key x-amz-website-redirect-location to my new location does not do anything.

how can I redirect the object from the s3 console please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [S3 web page redirect: can't set x-amz-website-redirect-location property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41133075/s3-web-page-redirect-cant-set-x-amz-website-redirect-location-property)

Comment: I am trying to set it up with the console, not sure how to do that. 
metadata key x-amz-meta-website-redirect-location does not work.

Comment: I set it up like in the example but it doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

In order to achieve redirection from an S3 object, the bucket has to be configured for static website hosting. You can check here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/how-to-page-redirect.html

After that setting `x-amz-website-redirect-location` property to the object metadata is going to work, but only from the s3 website endpoint (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/WebsiteEndpoints.html):

1. **s3-website dash (-) Region** ‐
   http://bucket-name.s3-website-Region.amazonaws.com
2. **s3-website dot (.) Region** ‐
   http://bucket-name.s3-website.Region.amazonaws.com

Unfortunately in your case even if you configure the bucket to be static your users are still using the https://myassets.s3.amazonaws.com/something.pkg which is not going to redirect.