# Cloudfront, lambda @ edge, S3 redirect objects,

Tags: redirect, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront, aws-lambda-edge

I am building an S3 URL redirect, nothing special just a bunch of zero-length objects with the WebsiteRedirectLocation meta filled out.  The S3 bucket is set to server static websites, bucket policy set to public, etc.  It works just fine.

HOWEVER - I also want to lock down certain files in the bucket - specifically some HTML files that serve to manage the redirects (like adding new redirects).  With the traditional setup, I can both use the redirects, and also serve the HTML page just fine.  But in order to lock it down, I need to use Cloudfront and Lambda@edge like in these posts:

https://douglasduhaime.com/posts/s3-lambda-auth.html

http://kynatro.com/blog/2018/01/03/a-step-by-step-guide-to-creating-a-password-protected-s3-bucket/

I have modified the lambda@edge script to only prompt for a password IF the admin page (or its assets like CSS/JS) are requested.  If the requested path is something else (presumably a redirect file) the user is not prompted for a password.  And yes, I could also set a behavior rule in Cloudfront to decide when to use the Lambda function to prompt for a password.

And it works kind of.  When I follow these instructions and visit my site via the Cloudfront URL, I do indeed get prompted for a password when I goto the root of my site - the admin page. However, the redirects will not work. If I try to load a redirect the browser just downloads it instead.

Now, [in another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22740084/amazon-s3-redirect-and-cloudfront) someone suggested that I change my Cloudfront distribution endpoint to the S3 bucket WEBSITE endpoint - which I think also means changing the bucket policy back to website mode and the public which sucks because now its accessible outside of the Cloudfront policy which I do not want.  Additionally - Cloudfront no longer automatically serves the specified index file, which isn't the worst thing.

SO - is it possible to lock down my bucket, the server it entirely through Cloudfront with Lambda@edge BUT also have Cloudfront respect those redirects instead of just prompting a download?  Is there a setting in Cloudfront to respect the headers?  Should I set up different behavior rules for the different files (HTML vs redirects)?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `WebsiteRedirectLocation` meta, which is specific to S3 static website hosting and has no effect when Cloudfront is the server, replace your empty objects with HTML objects that contain a `meta` HTML tag with the desired redirect target:

```
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; url=https://www.example.com" />
```

The number before the semicolon is the delay before the redirect, in seconds, where 0 is immediate.

Don't forget to also change the `Content-Type` meta tag of the objects to `text/html`.

And if you want to support old browsers that might not handle the Refresh directive correctly, add an anchor link as explained [here](https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/html/how-to-redirect-a-web-page-in-html.html).

Comment: oh thats an interesting idea, I'll give that a shot and report back later! thanks