# Cloudfront to s3 redirect to subdomain Access denied error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

Googling I found
[Cloudfront to s3 redirect to subdomain giving Access denied error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63178996/cloudfront-to-s3-redirect-to-subdomain-giving-access-denied-error)
which seems to be same issue.

In my case, I have [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) redirect to example.com

The CloudFront origin name selected from list was
[www.example.com.s3.amazonaws.com](http://www.example.com.s3.amazonaws.com)
and I edited to be
[www.example.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com](http://www.example.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com)

But still get error when I visit [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)

```
<Error>
   <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
   <Message>Access Denied</Message>
   <RequestId>xxxxx</RequestId>
   <HostId>yyyyyyyyyyy</HostId>
</Error>
```

Opening
[www.example.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com](http://www.example.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com)
in browser does the redirect properly

Opening

xxxxxxx.cloudfront.net
gives same error, so I assume the issue issue is with cloudfront

Answer (score 0):

So. I tried https://www.example.com again just now and it worked. Perhaps just took some time for settings to percolate.